# Can't determine Firebase Database URL ( Firebase Realtime Database)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, next.js, firebase-admin

I get into this error:

```
code: 'database/invalid-argument',
message: "Can't determine Firebase Database URL."
```

when trying to access to Firebase Realtime Database with Next.js

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

if (!admin.apps.length) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
      client_email: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      private_key: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY,
      project_id: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
    }),
    databaseURL: 'https://xxx-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app'
  });
}

export default admin.database();
```

I don't know what kind of error i'm running to? Please Help!
Thank you!

Comment: Your databaseURL looks a bit different from the ones in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.credential#cert)
`"https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"` Not sure if that is your issue

Comment: *firebaser here* What SDK version are you using? The `asia-southeast1` was introduced pretty recently, so you might need to upgrade your Admin SDK to the latest version. I'm checking with the team what the min version is, and will answer below when I have an answer.

Comment: thank you guys, i changed  `import admin from 'firebase-admin';` to `import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';` and the error disappear.